# How to pass lot of collection and custom data to another route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Based on user input value, I am calculating product price and price breakdown dynamically and showing the price to the user.

How can I pass an entire collection and breakdown to the next page (like a checkout page).

I can JSON encode whole collection and kept inside a form and passing by post request. In this case user might manipulate using browser developer tool.

What could be alternative way to pass big data to another route (checkout route) in laravel. I am logically stuck.

Comment: Typically, you have to pass the id of product to the next page, and then load sensible datas such as pricing from your database

Comment: Best practice is store relevant information to database corresponding that user_id before going to next page, And fetch from database once you reached to target page.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using session or local storage also

Solution Explanation:

1. Session Storage: store the data in session with user id and get it in next page and if you work is done then clearing the session.
2. Store the data in local storage and retrieve in next page then clear the storage.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to pass entire collection between the pages.

Let's say, you have a `person` stored with id as `1` in your database. Person has lot of other detail also stored like name, email, job etc etc

If passing data is concerned, you first fetch data of that person from database, pass to the next page and then via post get the same data back to you.

Whereas, just the `id` having value `1` is more than enough to identify that it is that person and you can get those detail back again.

Considering e-commerce and checkout page, when items are added in cart, it's a `cart quote`. The items are not checked out yet. So you can create a `cart_quotes` table to store that data and then just pass the id of quotation to the next page instead of entire details like products added to cart, discounts etc etc.

The next question comes : `id` can also be manipulated from the url? The answer is, laravel has [signed urls](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls#signed-urls) using which you can avoid url tampering.

Last but something I would recommend, if you are building an e-commerce in laravel, there are already packages available which does everything for you. Check :

```
- [vanilo](https://vanilo.io/)
- [aimeos](https://aimeos.org/laravel-ecommerce-package/)
- [bagisto](https://bagisto.com/en/)
```